How to pass arguments to fine-tuned yolov5 model?
I have some fine tuned weights, and I am trying to apply the model to an image, but I want to hide the image label and confidence interval. When I am running the model from the command line I would typically do --hide_label True --hide_conf True, but now when I am deploying the model withing a script, I'm unsure how to pass these arguments.
This is my current script:
I've tried passing the arguments to the model() and in the torch.hub.load() but it the arguments aren't recognized. I understand that this is because within the yolov5 repo it runs the detect.py script, but how would I pass arguments specifically to that?
import torch
from PIL import Image
path_to_model = "yolov5-training//yolov5//runs//train//exp17//weights//best.pt"
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path=path_to_model)

# Set device (CPU or GPU)
device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')

def detect_objects(image_path, save_path=None):
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    results = model(img)
    
    # Draw bounding boxes on the image
    results.show()

    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image_path = 'local_testing/IMG_4530.JPEG'
    save_path = 'detected_image.jpg'
    results = detect_objects(image_path, save_path)

